# How to add sections and subsections to chapters Overleaf/Latex

Tags: compilation, latex, overleaf

when working with folders in Overleaf I have a main.tex file and others including the chapters of my work, however, it's not possible to make the sections and subsections work properly in my chapters, they are added to the Cotents page without problems but are not taken as sections when compiling in PFD, here a patch of my code:

Main section:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,BCOR=12mm,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\input{packages}
%\makealeletter


\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\done}{\rlap{$\square$}{\raisebox{2pt}{\large\hspace{1pt}\cmark}}%
\hspace{-2.5pt}}

\input{settings}
\input{commands}
\input{pages/cover}

\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

    \definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{.035,.353,.651}
    \definecolor{White}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

    % front page
    \frontmatter{}
    
    \input{pages/title}
    \input{pages/disclaimer}
    \input{pages/abstract}
    \tableofcontents{}
    \input{pages/dedication}
    
    \mainmatter{}
    
    %\input{00_ToDo}
    \input{Chapters/00_intro.tex}
    \input{Chapters/01_Chapter1.tex}
    .
    .
    .
```

Chapter which I want to add sections and subsections:

```
%!TeX root = ../main.tex
\chapter{Chapter 1: Theoretical Perspective}\label{chapter:Chapter1}

\section{Remote Sensing}
.
.
.
```

And the result...

[image]

Actually I added the !Tex root = ... but didn't work, do you know guys what could actually been affecting the correct working of the Overleaf compilation?

I expect the correct displaying of the section but instead of that I get the results as presented in the attached image.

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I modified the question with more details, I hope it's more understandable.

Comment: We can't reproduce the problem as we don't have all the included files you use. Make a copy of your project and then boil it down until you have a minimal reproducible example.